# Windows XP & Ubuntu 12.10 shutdown problem

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, shutdown

Ubuntu 12.10 for some time has not been shutting down at all. It is showing some series of numbers and call trace message (I don't know anything about this). It did not shut down even after waiting for half an hour. I just turned the power off to shut it down. Can I have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Step 1: Go to terminal and type

```
 sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

It will open the grub file. Change the line

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"
```

and close it after saving.

> Step 2: Again hit the terminal and type

```
 sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

It will open the modules - just type `apm power_off=1` below lp and save the file.

> Step 3: Next type in the terminal

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Comment: do's this repare grub? & can you asy why this problem occures

Comment: no ..not grub repair...

Comment: can you say why this problem occures? & will any other properties will change if i do as you said Qasim

Comment: no properties will change, it only resolve your issue ...if you have any problem after this we are here to resolve it

Comment: ok tanks Qasim i did as u said